# What is the difference between "async with lock" and "with await lock"?

Tags: python, python-asyncio

I have seen two ways of acquiring the `asyncio` [Lock](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-sync.html#lock):

```py
async def main(lock):
  async with lock:
    async.sleep(100)
```

and

```py
async def main(lock):
  with await lock:
    async.sleep(100)
```

What is the difference between them?

Comment: `with await lock` is deprecated, and gone in Python 3.9. Don't use it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The second form `with await lock` is deprecated since Python 3.7 and is removed in Python 3.9.

Running it with Python 3.7 gives this warning:

> DeprecationWarning: 'with await lock' is deprecated use 'async with lock' instead

Sources (scroll to the bottom):

- https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/asyncio-sync.html
- https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/asyncio-sync.html

Answer (score 3):

there should be no functional difference

BUT
the latter was removed from python 3.9
see at the bottom of the page
https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-sync.html

> Changed in version 3.9: Acquiring a lock using await lock or yield from lock and/or with statement (with await lock, with (yield from lock)) was removed. Use async with lock instead.

Answer (score 0):

`async with lock` is an statement for asynchronous context manager which suspends execution in enter (`__aenter__` ) and exit (`__aexit__`) methods. `async with` is supported from Python 3.5 and is fully described in PEP 492. `with await lock` is the same but in Python 3.9 is officially removed and it is recommended to use `async with lock` instead.

Comment: Note that _in general_ `with await x` is not the same as `async with x`. It was just a hack that locks were made awaitable particularly so that `with await lock` would work. That hack was removed, but `with await x` is still valid syntax - you can await an object and use (the ordinary non-async) `with` on the result of the await. But that kind of thing is very rarely useful.